# Didn't understand how the splice method works in the recursion call for permutation purpose

Tags: javascript, recursion, slice, permutation, splice

I get little  trouble  with an algorithm about permutation well I found it in full-stack overflow

```
 function permutator(inputArr) {
  var results = [];

  function permute(arr, memo) {
    var cur, memo = memo || [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      cur = arr.splice(i, 1);
      if (arr.length === 0) {
        results.push(memo.concat(cur));
      }
      permute(arr.slice(), memo.concat(cur));
      arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]);(what's the purpose of this statement ????)
    }

    return results;
  }

  return permute(inputArr);
}
```

actually, I didn't understand how the recursion call  work exactly
I didn't understand how the splice method work in this recursion call I mean for example let's take an array of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]   in each iteration  we run   cur = arr.splice(i, 1)  normally we get cur =0 then cur = 2, then 4 then 6 and so on ..., so  when I log the memo and the arr variables in the console I got this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7lAP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a complex method to solve this type of problem, to understand this we need to simplify the problem,

After some modification this code is much readable!

```js
function permutator(inputArr) {
    var results = [];
    function permute(arr, memo = []) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            let temp = [...arr], mem = memo.concat(temp.splice(i, 1));
            if (temp.length === 0) results.push(mem);
            permute(temp, mem);
        }
    }
    permute(inputArr);
    return results
}
console.log(permutator([1, 2, 3]))
```

So basically in original code, they modify `arr` (only for short time) and later (in this line `arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]);`) restore back to it's original state.

`splice` method accept 3 arguments (`start, deleteCount?, ...items?`), And return an array containing the deleted elements. I recommend you to read more about [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice),

Example:

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log({ numbers })

let deleted_elements = numbers.splice(0, 2);
console.log('Removing first 2 elements from `numbers`', { deleted_elements, numbers })

numbers.splice(0, 0, ...deleted_elements);
console.log("Push `deleted_elements` in there original place", { numbers })
```

Comment: thank you so much would you please explain more about arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]); thanks thanks so muchhhh ( in each recursion call the arra variable is filled by the removed item?)

Comment: _"in each recursion call the arra variable is filled by the removed item?"_ - No, They basically delete element for a short time, And later  push that delete element in it original place,

Comment: for example if  the array   is  [1,2,3,4]   and i = 0  so the splice methode take each  element [1],[2],[3],[4] then   arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]) return them [1],[2],[3],[4]  to the original array , it's like creating a copy ?

Comment: Please read documentation about  [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: thank youthank you thank you thank you  so much for your help <3